# Join tables based on lagged date

Tags: sql, sas

I need to perform a LEFT JOIN to bring in a variable from table B to A by joining on the date with the new variable in Table B having a lagged date of the date in Table A:

Table A:

```
Date    Var1
1/3/07  1
```

Table B:

```
Date    Var2
1/2/07  2
1/3/07  3
```

JOINED TABLE:

```
Date   Var1  Var2
1/3/07  1    2
```

I need to do this for thousands of dates. This did not work:

```
 proc sql;
 create table data.Join as
 select a.*, b.Var2
 from data.A a left join data.B b
 on a.Date=b.Date
 where a.Date=lag(b.Date,1);
 quit;
```

Comment: What [RDBMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system) you are using? `RDBMS` stands for *Relational Database Management System*. `RDBMS is the basis for SQL`, and for all modern database systems like MS SQL Server, IBM DB2, Oracle, MySQL, etc...

Comment: the RDBMS matters to how easy the solution is. The version too eg SQL Server 2008 or SQL Server 2012

Comment: LAG does not do what you think it does.  The SQL-native solutions will work fine in SAS in this case.  LAG is only for data step (and even then won't do what you want it to do.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using SAS proc SQL, presumably.  In this, you can do regular arithmetic on dates, so `- 1` means subtract one day.  You can try this:

```
Select A.Date, A.Var1, B.Var2
From A left outer join
     B
     On A.Date = B.Date + 1
```

If there is no match, then the `left outer join` will keep the row and insert NULL for the third column.

Comment: Just another question: Your code works, but some do not match to the lagged 1 date in Table B because it falls on a Monday. For example, 1/15/07 in Table A needs to match to 1/12/07 in Table B. But when you change the above code to + 3 it doesn't match. Why?

Comment: @SASnewby . . . Well, those values should match.  Are you sure the "date" has no time component?  That would add decimal points to the value, often preventing a match.  If this is an issue, then do:  `on datepart(a.date) = datepart(b.date) + <whatever>`.

Comment: False alarm. I had created a table with the missing Var2 values so it already contained the Var2 with "." and it will not perform a left join. If you want to avoid having to pull the ones it doesn't match to because it needs to be lagged 3, what's the best way instead of having to merge the two tables with SQL?

Answer (score 0):

```
Select A.Date,A.Var1,B.Var2 From A
left join B On A.Date = B.Date
Where A.Date = ?
```

Given Var2 of null if there's record in table a is okay, if not you want an inner join instead of a left one.

Just noticed lag so instead of A.Date = B.date, you'd use whatever that means, need to know DBMS for exact syntax.