# MySQL join date columns with 1-month lag and performance issues

Tags: mysql, sql, date, join, lag

Note: I found [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16651909/join-tables-based-on-lagged-date) but it does not address my issue, so I do not believe this is a duplicate.

I have two simple MySQL tables (created with the MyISAM engine), `Table1` and `Table2`.

Both of the tables have 3 columns, a date-type column, an integer ID column, and a float value column. Both tables have about 3 million records and are very straightforward.

The contents of the tables looks like this (with `Date` and `Id` as primary keys):

```
Date        Id   Var1
2012-1-27    1    0.1
2012-1-27    2    0.5
2012-2-28    1    0.6
2012-2-28    2    0.7
```

(assume `Var1` becomes `Var2` for the second table).

Note that for each (year, month, ID) triplet, there will only be a single entry. But the actual day of the month that appears is not necessarily the final day, nor is it the final weekday, nor is it the final business day, etc... It's just some day of the month. This day is important as an observation day in other tables, but the day-of-month itself doesn't matter between `Table1` and `Table2`.

Because of this, I cannot rely on `Date + INTERVAL 1 MONTH` to produce the matching day-of-month for the date it should match to that is one month ahead.

I'm looking to join the two tables on `Date` and `Id` but where the values from the second table (`Var2`) come from 1-month ahead than `Var1`.

This sort of code will accomplish it, but I am noticing a significant performance degradation with this, explained below.

```
-- This is exceptionally slow for me
SELECT b.Date, 
       b.Id, 
       a.Var1, 
       b.Var2
FROM Table1 a
JOIN Table2 b
ON a.Id = b.Id
AND YEAR(a.Date + INTERVAL 1 MONTH) = YEAR(b.Date)
AND MONTH(a.Date + INTERVAL 1 MONTH) = MONTH(b.Date)


-- This returns quickly, but if I use it as a sub-query
-- then the parent query is very slow.
SELECT Date + INTERVAL 1 MONTH as FutureDate,
       Id,
       Var1
FROM Table1


-- That is, the above is fast, but this is super slow:
select b.Date, 
       b.Id, 
       a.Var1, 
       b.Var2
FROM (SELECT Date + INTERVAL 1 MONTH as FutureDate
             Id,
             Var1
      FROM Table1) a
JOIN Table2 b
ON YEAR(a.FutureDate) = YEAR(b.Date)
AND MONTH(a.FutureDate) = MONTH(b.Date)
AND a.Id = b.Id
```

I've tried re-ordering the `JOIN` criteria, thinking maybe that matching on `Id` first in the code would change the query execution plan, but it seems to make no difference.

When I say "super slow", I mean that option #1 from the code above doesn't return the results for all 3 million records even if I wait for over an hour. Option #2 returns in less than 10 minutes, but then option number three takes longer than 1 hour again.

I don't understand why the introduction of the date lag makes it take so long.

How can I

1. profile the queries to understand why it takes a long time?
2. write a better query for joining tables based on a 1-month date lag (where day-of-month that results from the 1-month lag may cause mismatches).

Comment: What about creating and indexing `dateYear` and `dateMonth` columns (as integers)? I believe that what's killing your performance is the use of the `YEAR` and `MONTH` functions.

Comment: This could work, but ideally I'd like to not have to propagate that around everywhere. There are actually hundreds of tables like `Table1` and `Table2` for which that process would need to take place. I suppose I could try a subquery that returns a column that is equal to `100*Year + Month` for `FutureDate` (in my second example) and see if that subquery is faster in the parent query, since the join would then just be on integer columns.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I am having a similar issue with slow JOINS using YEAR() and MONTH() conditions.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative approach:

```
SELECT b.Date, b.Id, b.Var2
       (select a.var1
        from Table1 a 
        where a.id = b.id and a.date < b.date
        order by a.date
        limit 1
       ) as var1
       b.Var2
FROM Table2 b;
```

Be sure the primary index is set up with `id` first and then `date` on `Table1`.  Otherwise, create another index `Table1(id, date)`.

Note that this assumes that the preceding date *is* for the preceding month.

Comment: The need for `Id` to be the first part of the primary index is so that the repeated subquery on each `Id` value (and ordering) will be fast enough?

Comment: @EMS . . . Yes, that is the reason.  You want the correlated subquery to use the index for the bulk of the work.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another alternative way to go about this:

```
SELECT thismonth.Date,
       thismonth.Id, 
       thismonth.Var1 AS Var1_thismonth,
       lastmonth.Var1 AS Var1_lastmonth
  FROM Table2 AS thismonth
  JOIN 
      (SELECT id, Var1, 
              DATE(DATE_FORMAT(Date,'%Y-%m-01')) as MonthStart
         FROM Table2
      ) AS lastmonth
    ON (     thismonth.id = lastmonth.id
         AND thismonth.Date >= lastmonth.MonthStart + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
         AND thismonth.Date <  lastmonth.MonthStart + INTERVAL 2 MONTH
        )
```

To get this to perform ideally, I think you're going to need a compound covering index on (id, Date, Var1).

It works by generating a derived table containing `Id,MonthStart,Var1` and then joining the original table to it by a sequence of range scans. Hence the compound covering index.

Comment: Won't `lastmonth.MonthStart + INTERVAL 1 MONTH` be greater than `thismonth.Date`? `MonthStart` just shifts it back to the `01` day of the same month. Adding a 1-month `INTERVAL` to that should give the `01` day of the next month, which is still greater than `thismonth.Date`, no?

Comment: Well, lastmonth.MonthStart is the first day of last month. To match it up to rows whose Date is on or after the start of the present month is to use `thismonth.Date >= lastmonth.MonthStart + INTERVAL 1 MONTH`.  Similarly, to match it up to rows whose date is before the start of next month is to use `thismonth.Date < lastmonth.MonthStart + INTERVAL 2 MONTH`. I double-checked this, and I'm pretty sure it's correct.

Comment: By the way, substitute LEFT JOIN for JOIN if you need result set rows for months having no observation for the preceding month. You'll get NULL values for those cases.  @GordonLinoff 's answer does that too.

Comment: I see, the inequality conditions make sense to me now. Thank you for clarifying.

Comment: Righto. Date inequalities are a notorious pitfall. I usually define a stored function called `TRUNC_MONTH()` to handle the `DATE(DATE_FORMAT(Date,'%Y-%m-01'))` operation, for ease of reading.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers gave very useful tips, but ultimately, without making significant modifications to the index structure of my data (which is not feasible at the moment), those methods would not work faster (in any meaningful sense) than what I had already tried in the question.

Ollie Jones gave me the idea to use date formatting, and coupling that with the `TIMESTAMPDIFF` function seems to make it passably fast, though I still welcome any comments explaining why the use of `YEAR`, `MONTH`, `DATE_FORMAT`, and `TIMESTAMPDIFF` have such wildly different performance properties.

```
SELECT b.Date, 
       b.Id,
       b.Var2,
       a.Date,
       a.Id,
       a.Var1
FROM Table1 a 
JOIN Table2 b 
ON a.Id = b.Id
AND (TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, 
                   DATE_FORMAT(a.Date, '%Y-%m-01'), 
                   DATE_FORMAT(b.Date, '%Y-%m-01')) = 1)
```